# HTTP ingress type Apache Flink StateFun

Tags: apache-flink, flink-statefun

I am trying to quickly put together a proof of concept using the Apache Flink statefun Docker image.

https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/flink-statefun

I don't really want to use Kafka or Kinesis as an ingress, I'd rather just use HTTP so I can quickly test and prototype. Is this possible?

The only ingress examples I can find are for Kafka like:

```
kind: io.statefun.kafka.v1/ingress
spec:
  id: com.ingress/Sentiment
  address: kafka-broker:9092
  consumerGroupId: sentiment-reader
  topics:
    - topic: sentimentegress
      valueType: SentimentEvent
      targets:
        - sentiment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no HTTP ingress. You could probably put one together fairly easily using the Kafka Connect HTTP connector, but that would obviously involve setting up Kafka and Kafka Connect.

Comment: although not directly related to the question, do you know how the function's instance ID is defined in case of kinesis ingress? in case of kafka, the instance ID is going to be a "key" of kafka record, what about kinesis?

Comment: nvm, looks like it's a partition key. i didn't know that kinesis consumer is aware of partition key, since it's chosen by sender and is used to forward the record to a particular shard, so i thought there's little sense for consumer to be aware of it